# generate xml and xsl from php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xslt, simplexml

i am trying to generate xml from mysql database. The application does not need to know the tables that exist in the database.

the function is such that you enter the table name and it generates the xml for it.

The function works perfect but i need to style the xml with xsl. since the application does not know which table it is going to handle, writing a predefined xsl has fialed to work.

can someone suggest how i might programmatically write an xsl along with the generated xml.

the function is pasted below.

PHP to generate XML (genXMl.php):

```
<?
header("content-type:text/xml");


if(isset($_GET['tbl']))
{

    $myServer = "localhost";
    $myUser = "user";
    $myPass = "pwd";
    $myDB = "test";
    $table = $_GET['tbl'];

    function getXML($sql="Default Query")
    {
        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pwd");
        $db=mysql_select_db("test");
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

        $columns="";
        echo "<records>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $columns.="<record>";
            foreach($row as $key => $value)
            {
                $columns.="<$key>$value</$key>";
            }
                $columns.="</record>";
        }
        echo $columns;
        echo "</records>";
    }
    getXML("SELECT * FROM $table");

}
```

THE XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My header</h2>
    <table border="1">

      <xsl:for-each select="records/record">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="<?php echo $key; ?>" /></td> //trying to style the $KEY
      </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="<?php echo $value;?>"/></td> //trying to style the $VALUE    </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can't embed PHP tags in an XSL stylesheet like that, you can't invoke a transform and a PHP script at the same time.  I'd either omit the XSL step and output the styled HTML directly or have the `getXML()` function return a DOM object which you can invoke against a Stylesheet.  Check out `DomDocument->load()`

Comment: You are building XML by concatenating strings. Don't do that. Use `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define xml tags as key from your database, but defining an unique structure for your xml that you can validate using a DTD or XSD.

Then, your XSL will be really simple.

For example, instead of that :

```
$columns.="<$key>$value</$key>";
```

You could do something like:

```
$columns.="<key name=\"$key\">$value</key>";
```

And then, your xsl would be simple to make :)

And as mentionned in the comments by @Tomalak, you should use DOMDocument instead of concatenating strings.